# find count of dragged rows count in excel suing vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing VBA Code for applying round functionality for one column in excel.

Here i am rounding successfully for one column using below code.

```
 If Target.Column = 18 Then 
  If Target.Value = 0 Then
   Target.Value = ""
    Else
      Target.Value = Round(Target.Value, 0)  
   End If
```

It is working for one column rounding perfectly like.

Ex:255.50 to 256.

But my question whenever i enter 255.50 and drag the 255.50 to come range assume for 4 cells.Here i am able to apply rounding for particular target cell only not for all dragged range of cells.

For this i want to find then dragged cells range in sheet and want to apply rounding for all dragged colums too.

Please give me any suggestions.

I am printing my actual output and my desired output below please refer those.

**Actual output:**

256

255.5

255.5

255.5

255.5

255.5

**Desired Output:**

256

256

256

256

256

256

Please help me out..

Comment: You cannot find a "dragged" cell once it was "dragged"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rounding off the values and therefore losing the original input number, you could achieve the rounding you want by using number formatting.

Assuming `Target` is a `Range` object in your code above, instead of calling `Round()` you could do:

```
Target.NumberFormat = "0" ' Round to no decimal digits
```

This way, the display number in the cell appears rounded as expected, but the *original* number remains in the cell. So, if in the future you decide to round to a single decimal number, you could change the formatting as follows:

```
Target.NumberFormat = "0.0" ' Round to 1 decimal digit
```

and it should all still work fine, since the original number is still there -- you're just formatting/displaying it differently.

Answer (score 0):

place your actual numbers in A column like below

```
Cell A1= 256
Cell A2=255.5
Cell A3=255.5
Cell A4=255.5
Cell A5=255.5
Cell A6=255.5
```

and place the below formula in cell B1

```
=ROUND(A1,0)
```

and drag the cells B1 to B6.